# Regex find utm letter from string

Tags: python, regex

```
coordinate = "  CENTR. MERID.: 03,    UTM ZONE: 31 N, FALSE EASTING: 500000    "
```

with using regex I am trying to extract utm zone `31` and utm letter `N`

I was able to extract utm zone by

```
utm_zone = re.search('UTM ZONE: (\d+)',coordinate).group(1)
```

but I cannot get utm letter

Comment: What is UTM and where is it in the sample text? Where is the zone and letter you specify ? How do you get those? I see UTM ZONE: in the regex, but I don't see UTM LETTER:. What do you mean ?

Comment: @sln utm letter is the letter right after 31, which is `N`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your looking for two different matches in one text, you can extract them both by using two groups.

```
coordinate = "  CENTR. MERID.: 03,    UTM ZONE: 31 N, FALSE EASTING: 500000    "
match_result = re.search('UTM ZONE: (\d+) ([A-Z]+)',coordinate)
```

Then you can get them as individual variables with the group function, as you did before.

```
utm_zone, utm_letter = match_result.group(1), match_result.group(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This expression might likely return those:

```
import re

regex = r"utm\s+zone\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*([A-Z]+)"

test_str = """
CENTR. MERID.: 03,    UTM ZONE: 31 N, FALSE EASTING: 500000    
CENTR. MERID.: 03,    UTM ZONE: 12 SE, FALSE EASTING: 500000    
CENTR. MERID.: 03,    utm  zone : 24  SW, FALSE EASTING: 500000 

"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE))
```

#### Output

```
[('31', 'N'), ('12', 'SE'), ('24', 'SW')]
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/g7U4qJ/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/g7U4qJ/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]